# Image/form to Pascal/Delphi code converter?

Tags: image, delphi, forms, canvas, pascal

Does anyone knows about any editor allowing to visually design a form (by form I do not mean DFM or Delphi form, but a "paper form", like those pre-printed forms that you fill with some info) and that generates pascal commands to draw that form in a Printer (or Image) canvas?

What I want is an easy way to draw/design this form visually, composed just by lines and text, and a way to convert this to Pascal commands that when run, will draw that form in a Canvas (Image or Printer), respecting the original layout and scale, doesn't matter the Canvas DPI where it is being drawn.

Update: Maybe I wasn't clear enough about what I need and why I need it. I developed an Open Source component called TFreeBoleto (freeboleto.sf.net). It is used to generate and print bank billets (a common method for billing people in Brazil). Right now, the component uses a TBitmap image containing the "billet" mask, and TextOut methods for the dynamic areas (ie: billet number, customer name, etc). It is fine when looked in the screen, but some people complains that the quality of the printed image is not good. The component uses a BltTBitmapAsDib procedure to maximize the quality of printing, but some people still think it is not good enough. So, my idea was to avoid using a bitmap image as the form layout, and draw everything direct in the canvas (both form and printer). [Check here for a sample of what a bank billet looks like](http://images.fedex.com/images/shared/lac/boleto/boleto_citibank_lac2.jpg).

Of course ReportBuilder and/or FastReport could solve the problem, but they are not free, so I cannot include it in the component. I need "native" solution that any standard Delphi install would be able to compile.

Comment: It sounds to me like you need a vector graphics editor package with text and line objects that can edit and view and print WMF, EMF, or SVG files.  If so, then the "code converter" part of your title and question is completely wrong.

Comment: Warren, my first desire is to have everything in pure pascal. I could do it using textout and other "draw" methods direct on the canvas, but this would be really time consuming. That's why I thought about some visual editor that would let me visually draw what I need, and it would convert that to "pascal" commands.

Comment: Hmm. That is an interesting concept, but I really think you'd be better off with a meta-file (WMF) plus some x,y dynamic text overlays, not code-to-draw-the-picture.  You might be interested in knowing that MetaFiles are really just a serialized form of Win32 GDI calls.  So, if you like, they are code (GDI API Calls) stored in a file.

Answer (score 3):

You might get what you want out of the Fast Reports Report Designer which is a commercial reporting system for Delphi.  Remember that a report is just a page.  That page can be shown on the screen or printed on the printer.

You also might find that something like TRichView helps you.

Whether using TRichView in particular or not, I would look into using HTML to do what you want.  I would use HTML+CSS to do both a screen and printer layout, that can also be viewed on the web. For simple text layout plus text boxes I think even bare HTML and HTML tables might be sufficient. To visually design simple text pages, using a Delphi application, I would use TRichView.

In both cases, you would be creating documents, not code.  To create code that creates a page, without using any document system, would be very difficult indeed, and I am not sure what you would really do with that code, since you would need a compiler or interpreter to convert that code into something that you could use. Please clarify what you mean by "creating code", and what syntax you would want that code to be using.  If HTML is code in your definition of "code" then maybe HTML is the best kind of "code" for your problem.

Comment: Please check my update to the original question. I don't think TRichView is "powerful" enough to handle the formatting I would need.

Comment: Your question has become pretty much unanswerable, even after editing it.

Answer (score 1):

I do my form-work with [WPTools](http://wpcubed.com). It is also a commercial product. The core is a very good wordprocessor and form-designer. The engine can render text and forms to any canvas (screen, printer, also create pdf) and is highly flexible. Output is mainly rtf and html.

I also see no advantage in creating pascal code to redraw the form. What you need, i think, is a good WYSIWYG-editor which creates a document that fits your needs.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I cannot use commercial components.

Answer (score 1):

Check out ReportBuilder @    http://www.digital-metaphors.com/

It is a commercial reporting tool for Delphi - around a long time, very high quality, with all native Delphi source code packaged with it. I am using it for an important commercial project right now and I recommend it highly (I'm not working for them.) I've used **MANY** Delphi reporting tools over the years and this one is the best IMO.

RBuilder also has extensive support for paper form emulation see: 
http://www.digital-metaphors.com/products/report_design/form_emulation.html

I haven't worked with that feature, but you can download a full-featured demo and try it.

Comment: Please check the update of my original question. I can't use commercial components for this.

Comment: If you're delivering a fully packaged ready to install/run component, even if it's open source, you don't need to include commercial packages that you used to build the component - that is all compiled and linked into your distributable binary - just make sure you don't distribute with 'run time packages'.

Answer (score -1):

Yoy can use Adobe Acrobat (full version) to create forms.

Then you can use free Acrobat Reader to display and print forms or other COM object in your application.

I think it is best solution for you.

PS
All tools for reports that are included in Delphi are free for you to design form and are free to distribute if user only preview and print already designed reports.

The same is valid for Adobe Acrobat (you may distribute forms) but you have added that you need to print form and some text over form. Maybe it is easier if you use reports but it is possible to do the same using PDF.

Most report engines are not open source but are free to distribute. There is many components for creating PDF - paid (one time), free, as well as open source.

**PPS
I have read your updete for second time. Since you are using TBitmap and you can to TextOut so: You can use TMetafile. There is many editors for metafiles and it is free to distribute metafiles.**

Comment: This is a programming answers site.  I believe the OP is asking about how to write software, not how to install other people's software.

Comment: I can not find any code in other posts but suggestions for using most suitable library. And I don't think that it is evil to use good and proven library instead writing code from scratch.

Comment: I remember reading some discussions where people said that using Metafile doesnt work as expected in 100% of the cases. Looks like it has some problems with streching, etc. and some incompatibilities with some printers drivers. I'll re-check metafile information anyway, and maybe do some tests.

Comment: Using a library versus using a complete ready-to-use program are completely different things.